# SQL error on joining two tables with two criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to join two tables with two criteria but it's giving me an error of

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 4 Cannot resolve the collation
>   conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and
>   "Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS" in the equal to operation.

Then I added COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS at the end but giving me an error of

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLLATE'.

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT        A.*, B.SEARCH_QUERY
FROM          Customer AS A 
LEFT JOIN     LOGS_Store AS B 
ON (A.SYS_CREATED_ON = B.REQUEST_TIME and A.SYS_CREATED_BY = B.USER_ID) 
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use collate after the field you want to collate:

```
ON (A.SYS_CREATED_ON = B.REQUEST_TIME 
and A.SYS_CREATED_BY COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS = B.USER_ID)
```